# Android app localization with sqlite db

Tags: android, delphi, sqlite, localization, google-play

Well, i have an android app created in delphi xe7. And i use sqlite data base to store all text there (use it for windows application and android version).

During the first start the program asks user to choose language and then it downloads language data base and some resources from program site. Also user can change language in run time.

But when I've added different language description on google play, it noted me, that my apk file is not localized.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem because Google expects you to create different folders inside your res/ folder for each languge that your app supports.

For example if you have french there should be a file called `res/values-fr/strings.xml` and if you support spanish there should be a file called `res/values-es/strings.xml`

This link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html explains more.

All is not lost. You can easily write a few lines of code to read your sqlite database and convert those strings into strings.xml files that will keep google happy.

Comment: it is easier to ignore the warning as long as users will not notice a difference between db or xml based localization

Answer (score 0):

If this this only a hint which is shown in your Google Play Developer Console, but not to your users, then there is no need to worry about it. Your store descriptions can be localized while your app does not use the platfom way to provide the string resource translations.